# How to use scala-js in the ammonite shell (amm)

Tags: shell, sbt, scala.js

Is it possible to load scala.js in the ammonite shell? [(amm)](http://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/)

I tried something like this:

```
load.ivy("org.scala-js" %% "scalajs-stubs" % "0.6.5")
```

but it does not work, I guess because *amm* does not know the proper sbt plugin.

So my question is maybe how to add a sbt plugin into amm in order to make scala.js work in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lihaoyi would be the authority on this, but I'd be surprised if it was possible.  Remember that Scala.js is all about how to run Scala inside of a JavaScript environment. Ammonite *isn't* inside of such an environment, so it's not obvious how it could work...

Comment: Yes you're probably right, I realize that my question is stupid. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it stupid. It's natural to want a REPL for Scala.js, and if someone made one, it's logical to think that some of the implementation could be shared with an existing REPL like Ammonite.